# Problems Break Out Into War

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have some question about a possible usage error [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_Affair):

> An American diplomatic commission was sent to France in July 1797 to negotiate ***problems*** that were threatening to ***break out into war***.

Is it standard English to write "*the problems broke out into war*"?  I cannot find this usage of "*break out*" in dictionaries.

Comment: Your feeling is right. It is no optimal formulation, but journalistic text, often written under pressure of time or edited several times when the text was too long, etc.

Comment: Pimples that appear suddenly are said to break out. A person with pimples is said to be "breaking out". A person can be "breaking out in a rash".  Fires are often said to break out. A fist-fight can break out. http://tinyurl.com/pvhv9xd

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically correct. You wouldn't find something like *the problems broke out into war* in dictionaries.

*"verb  1.  break out - start abruptly; "After 1989, peace broke out in the former East Bloc"*

Answer (score 0):

While it is grammatically correct, it is certainly not a common useage, and is almost certainly a slip by the author of the Wiki article. Ngram, for instance, shows no examples at all of "broke out into war".

The author was thinking of the phrase "war broke out", which has widespread useage.
[image]
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=war+broke+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwar%20broke%20out%3B%2Cc0

Note the peaks at 1918 and 1942.